# Answering based on original question

Tags: discussion, answers

Here's a situation...

I give a valid answer for a question based on what the OP posted at first. Then OP comes back and tells that this answer is not what he wanted because OP has got some more *constraints/conditions* (which OP didn't mention in the original question -- posted at first).

If I can update my answer based on additional conditions that OP posted then I'll usually do it. But if I do not have expertise to answer that question with the additional conditions, what should I do? Should I just delete my answer?

What's the best way to proceed in this situation?

Comment: You can edit it and add details to it (with a note that this is an addition based on additional data from the OP).

Comment: @Oded: Not if you "do not have expertise to answer that question with the additional conditions".

Comment: Related: [Exit strategies for “chameleon questions”](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions)

Comment: So this *is* a duplicate ... I should have guessed so.

Comment: It's not a duplicate (as Manishearth pointed out), and I wasn't proposing it as such.

Answer (score 1):

Of course, this is *related* to [Exit strategies for "chameleon questions"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions) , as noted by TheEstablishment, but unfortunately, it's sort of useless here--since the non-dupe assumes that you *can* answer the new question, just that you don't *want* to.

It's happened to me a few times--I answer a seemingly simple question, and then the OP, on seeing my answer, clarifies the intent and makes it much more complicated.

In this case, what I do it depends upon my answer. If I gave a short answer to an exceedingly simple question, it goes down the memory hole. Actually, all short answers go down the memory hole on a change of question.

If I gave a longish answer to a not-too-complicated but hard initial question, I keep it and hat it with "this answered the original question which was blah". Usually, the post still contains some useful concepts and explanations, and while it does not *answer* the question, it definitely helps.

If I gave a long answer to a simple question, it really depends. I guess the checklist for keeping an answer is:

- Does it answer the question?
- If not, is it a significant step towards answering the question?
- If not, does it explain relevant concepts which may help the OP understand the situation better and/or answer the problem himself?
- If not, memory hole!

But that's just my opinion--and note that it is based on my experiences on Physics.SE--usually SO answers don't explain concepts so it may be different there.